# What is the difference between "someValuesFrom" and "allValuesFrom"?

Tags: math, logic, owl, description-logic

In description logic, what is the difference between "someValuesFrom" and "allValuesFrom"?
In other words, the difference between (limited existential quantification) and (value restriction).

For example, consider this:

∆ = {a, b, c, d, e}
   ext(B) = {<c,d>}
   ext(R) = {<a,b>, <a,c>, <d,c>, <c,e>}

So what is the difference between the following?

ext(∃R. B) = *?*
   ext(∀R. B) = *?*

Is there any way to simplify the concept of somevaluefrom and allvaluesfrom?

Comment: ext(R) is a set of _pairs_, the picture should be: {<a,b>, <a,c>, ...}

Answer (score 6):

First, `allValuesFrom` and `someValuesFrom` sound like OWL, and they are explained with examples in the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-owl-guide-20040210/#allValuesFrom).

In the context of OWL (which is a DL language) they respresent restrictions on properties, especially on the class of the property values, meaning e.g. that you want to state that a `Car`, which has a `manufactured_by` property, this property is restricted to members of the Class `Manufacturer`.

`allValuesFrom` and `someValuesFrom` differ in the sense, that the first requires all values of the property values, the latter at least one to be of a certain class.